# How to make rlwrap tab complete a word that was fully typed?

Tags: readline, rlwrap

I use [rlwrap](https://github.com/hanslub42/rlwrap) to get `readline` features not available by default (on Ubuntu) in interactive consoles such as `gnuplot`, `sqlite3`.

It allows one to specify a completion word list in a file `~/.<command>_completions`. Consider this example using `bash`:

```
rlwrap‸<TAB>
rlwrap ‸
```

And this one, using `rlwrap`:

```
echo rlwrap > ~/.bash_completions
rlwrap -a bash
rlwrap‸<TAB>
rlwrap‸
rlwra‸<TAB>
rlwrap ‸
```

Is it possible to have `rlwrap` behave like `bash` in this regard and complete a word that has been typed in full?

It's especially frustrating when using case insensitive completion to complete upper case sqlite keywords. If it worked as expected I could hit `TAB` after each keyword instead of space and have it converted to uppercase. Currently, the keywords I type in full are lower case and tab completed are upper case, which offends my aesthetic sensibilities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was an issue with earlier versions of `rlwrap`.

It [has been fixed in version 0.42](https://github.com/hanslub42/rlwrap/blob/master/NEWS), that is the most recent as of today. It is [not yet packaged for Ubuntu](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=rlwrap), but you can grab a [source archive](http://utopia.knoware.nl/~hlub/uck/rlwrap/) that is very straightforward to build.